# Python: Scipy.optimize Levenberg-marquardt method

Tags: python, scipy

Tengo una duda en cómo usar el método de optimización Levenberg-Marquart en [python](/questions/tagged/python).

En la libreria [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) vienen varios de estos métodos:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

He probado dos métodos (nelder-mead y basinhopping) y funcionan correctamente con la siguiente sentencia:

Nelder mead:

```
res0_10 = optimize.minimize(f0_10,
                            x0, 
                            method='Nelder-Mead',
                            options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 2000})
```

Basinhopping

```
res0_10 = optimize.basinhopping(f0_10, x0, niter=100, disp=True)
```

El problema surge cuando uso el Levenberg-Marquardt (copio solo la parte del error, el programa es largo por eso no copio el resto):

```
def f0_10(x):
   m, u, z, s  = x
   for i in range(alt_max):
       if i==alt_min: suma=0
       if i > alt_min:
          suma = suma + (B(x, i)-b0_10(x, i))**2
   return np.sqrt(suma/alt_max)

x0 = np.array([40., 0., 500., 50.])

res0_10 = root(f0_10, x0, jac=True, method='lm')
```

El programa compila bien, pero a la hora de ejecutar, me surge el siguiente error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Quini SB\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__ return self.func(*args)

File "C:\Users\Quini SB\Desktop\tfg\Steyn - levmar.py", line 384, in askopenfilename res0_10 = root(f0_10, x0, jac=True, method='lm')

File "C:\Users\Quini SB\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_root.py", line 188, in root sol = _root_leastsq(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac,
**options)

File "C:\Users\Quini SB\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_root.py", line 251, in _root_leastsq factor=factor, diag=diag)

File "C:\Users\Quini SB\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 377, in leastsq shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)

File "C:\Users\Quini SB\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))

File "C:\Users\Quini SB\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 64, in __call__ self.jac = fg[1]

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

No tengo muy claro a qué se debe, soy estudiante y lo necesito para el TFG, pero mi profesor no controla [python](/questions/tagged/python), así que probablemente será una tontería, pero no soy capaz de solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Dónde defines `alt_min` y `alt_max`y qué valores tienen?

Comment: ¿y qué se supone que es `root`? Investiga mejor qué es lo que tiene que devolver la función que usas. Seguramente debería retornar un valor **y un gradiente**.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback?? me hace pensar que esta usando tkinter y root = Tk() por lo que no tiene sentido esa sentencia, y por eso arroja ese error

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que la función `root` a la que estás llamando no es la correcta, sino la del módulo `Tkinter`.

Si reemplazas `root` por `scipy.optimize.root` debiese funcionar, siempre que hayas importado `scipy.optimize` en tu programa.

Nótese que si lo importaste con un alias, esto es

```
import scipy.optimize as opti
```

Entonces puedes usar la función `root` bajo dicho alias:

```
res0_10 = opti.root(f0_10, x0, jac=True, method='lm')
```

Comment: ¿Tal vez `from TKinter import *` al principio del todo? :)

Comment: @astrojuanlu No, porque en este caso quiere usar una función `root` que nada tiene que ver con la de `Tkinter`

Comment: A eso voy: él piensa que está usando la de SciPy. Habría que ver cómo ha hecho los imports para saber cuándo se ha traído root de Tkinter.

Comment: Pensé que sugerías *agregar* dicho import ;). Estamos de acuerdo en que posiblemente su programa tiene un import de ese estilo. De todos modos, tal vez lo necesita así que a priori no recomendaría removerlo.

Answer (score 0):

El `indexerror` indica que hubo un error al intentar accesar una posicion inexistente en la memoria. Lo que indica que haz intentado accesar un arreglo de forma erronea.